# What is the maximum possible sum?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics

What is the maximum possible sum of the elements one can choose from the set $\{1, 2, . . . , 99 \}$ such that all their pairwise sums $a_i + a_j , i < j$, would be different?

Comment: I could only find an answer with the assumption of 99,98 and 97 would be included in the sum, which gives the answer 856. But then i figured there might be a bigger answer if we could include more numbers to the sum. And I can't find a way to optimize it.

Comment: Have you tried to brute-force it for the set $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ with smaller $n$ to see whether there's a pattern?

Comment: I tried but had the same problem. Had to make some kind of assumption in order to calculate many sets, because it takes too long to try all the possibliities.

Comment: Well, for $3\le s \le 197$ there are $\lfloor \frac {\min(s,200-s)-1} 2 \rfloor$ pairs that sum to $s$, so it makes sense that we should try for as many of these as possible, and try to get the most mileage we can out of the ones with lots of options.  If we choose $k$ elements, we have $k \choose 2$ pairs, so with $195$ distinct sums possible we have $20$ as an upper bound on $k$.

Comment: Expanding on that, if we were able to choose $20$ such elements so as to cover the $190$ largest possible pairwise sums, the overall sum of the pairwise sums would be $\sum_{i=8}^{197} i=19285$ which would include each of our $k$ elements $19$ times, giving $\frac {19285} {19} =1015$ as an upper bound.

Comment: The pairwise sums being distinct is equivalent to the pairwise differences being distinct, but while there are $195$ possible sums, there are only $98$ possible differences, reducing the upper bound on $k$ to $14$.  Oddly, this doesn't reduce the upper bound for the overall sum.  It seems to *increase* it to $1057$, implying that there's something wrong with my reasoning (or my calculations), though I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i \in\{1,\dots,99\}$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether element $i$ is selected.  For each pair $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le 99$, let binary (optionally, nonnegative) decision variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether that pair appears (that is, $y_{i,j}=x_i x_j$).  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^{99} i x_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_i + x_j - 1 &\le y_{i,j} &&\text{for $1 \le i < j \le 99$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i<s-i} y_{i,s-i} &\le 1 &&\text{for $s\in\{3,\dots,197\}$} \tag2 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces the logical implication $x_i \land x_j \implies y_{i,j}$, equivalently, $x_i x_j \le y_{i,j}$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces that each pairwise sum $s$ appears at most once.
As @Gabriel Burns observed, you can optionally impose an additional constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{99} x_i \le 20$.

The maximum sum turns out to be $879$, attained by $$\{17,35,53,65,70,75,84,91,95,97,98,99\}.$$

Comment: The value 879 and the corresponding subset are in agreement with the data found in [A280944](https://oeis.org/A280944).

Answer (score 1):

I'll start things off with 856.

Set {99, 98, 97, 95, 92, 87, 79, 70, 61, 47, 26, 5} obtained with the greedy method. I tried a few other starting seeds and got lower values.

This is 100 - [A011185](http://oeis.org/A011185).

The phrase you'll need to search is [Sidon sequence](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407117).  This is a 12-term Sidon sequence.  According to the linked paper, the densest 13-term Sidon sequence uses the number 101, just above your cut-off.  Therefore, the greedy 12-term sequence is best.

Comment: Which makes it **the** answer, because "distinct pairwise sums" $\leftrightarrow$ "distinct pairwise differences" and $\max_I (\sum_{i\in I} i) \leftrightarrow \min_I \left( \sum_{i\in I} 100-i \right)$ for constant $|I|$ .

Comment: Wait, never mind.  I just realized that the minimum sum of numbers less than $n$ with distinct sums numbers isn't necessarily the sum of all numbers less than $n$ in the sequence.  And even if it is, there may be such a sum with more total numbers, which matters for the maximizing case. I still suspect this is right, though.

Comment: Doesn't {1, 2, 3, 5, 9} contradict the assertion? There are no pairs with the same sum but two pairs have the same difference: 2-1 = 1 and 3-2 = 1. Or do you mean that pairs with no elements in common have distinct differences?

Comment: The set {1,2,3,5,9} is not a Sidon set, when you are checking the conditions for Sidon set, you also have to consider adding number to itself, so here we get 2+2 = 3+1 and therefore it is not Sidon. Actually there are no subsets of {1,2,...,9} of cardinality 5 which are Sidon (see oeis.org/A241689 ). The set {1,2,5,10,12} is Sidon.